# I'm having trouble creating a code that hides columns based on a cell entry

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code in Excel VBA that will hide columns based on an entry in Cell D6. The user will enter an integer (1-5), press the button I created, and then only the corresponding column will be shown, all others will be hidden. 
For example, if they enter 1 into Cell D6 I want to hide columns D through G. If they enter 4, I'd hide C, D, E, and G.

I'm very new to VBA so I've been watching youtube and looking at still cant work through it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim the_selection As String
Dim band_in_review As String


the_selection = Sheet1.Range("D6")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To 7
        the_column = Columns(i).Select
        band_in_review = Sheet1.Range(the_column & "4")
            If the_selection = band_in_review Then
            Sheet1.Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Else
            Sheet1.Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHJ6x.png)

Comment: What type is `the_column`, and what is expected out of `Columns(i).Select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: based on your screenshot

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim theBand As String

    theBand = "OEB " & Sheet1.Range("K5").Value

    For i = 3 To 7
        Sheet1.Columns(i).Hidden = (theBand <> Sheet1.Cells(9, i).Value)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This definitely makes what I was trying to do a lot simpler, thanks for that! However, running the code hides every column. I'm trying to hide every column except for the column that corresponds to the entry in D6.

Comment: I think the issue is that my input is a value 1-5 and i runs from 3 to 7. When I do an input value of 5 it works but just shows the wrong column. How can I account for this in my code?

Comment: What's the significance of `band_in_review` though?  It looks like you read something from Row4 to decide whether to hide/show the column.  Is that not relevant?

Comment: band_in_review refers to the current iteration of the for loop and which column it was looking at. In my document the titles of the 5 columns I'm looking at are Band 1, Band 2, etc. Basically what I was trying to do was check to see if the band_in_review was equal to the_selection (which is the column I want to isolate/input value by user). If it was equal, then the if statement would be False and it would NOT hide that column. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Any chance you can post a screenshot of your sheet?

Comment: See screenshot posted above. Note I moved the input box to a different cell location.